# How to add a character to folder names when using the ls command?

Tags: bash

I would like to display a character at the beginning of all folder names when typing the ls command.

So instead of this:

```
ls

Folder-1    Folder-2    file.txt
```

It displays this:

```
ls

Folder-1    Folder-2    file.txt
```

Is there a script I can write in my .bash_profile to do this?

Comment: Try this: `ls -G` (roses are red, violets are blue, files are red, and folders are _not_)

Comment: You may use `ls -F` for classifying file types

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom script that makes it for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

lsmod=($(ls)) # Convert ls output to an array
for folder in ${lsmod[@]}; do # Iterate over ls results
        if [[ -d $folder ]]; then # If this is a folder then...
                echo "=> $folder" # Put your char
        else # If not, display normally
                echo "$folder"
        fi
done
```

Folders are pointed out with a `=>`. Hope this helps.

One line approach:

```
for i in `ls`; do echo $([[ -d "$i" ]] && echo "=> $i" || echo "$i"); done;
```

Comment: From readability standpoint I think if `folder` can be something other than folder  it should be named differently. :)

Comment: You don't have convert the output of `ls` into an array. Writing the for loop as `for folder in $(ls); do .... done` is enough and even better to read.

Comment: This will output all folders in the current directory, but is it possible to replace with regular "ls" functionality with this new one?